# Can you get/re-use a promise from a future object when you're done with the future object

Tags: c++

is there code that works like this?

```
promise<type> p;
future<type> f{p.get_future()};
..thread stuff...
f.get();
//now the important part |
//                       v

p=f.get_promise();
```

Comment: Why do you want to get the promise back from the future? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @AlanBirtles no reason, i am not trying to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a promise from a future at all. And once a promise's value is set, it cannot be changed.

You could reset a particular `std::promise` object by move-assigning from a freshly created `promise`, but no `future` attached to it would be updated. They would all be looking at the previous shared state, not the new one.